# Powershell: how to get logged-in users list in active directory?

Tags: script, powershell, active-directory

I need to generate this table:

```
Computer | User | last log in date(never)
```

[This one](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Active-Directory-User-bbcdd771) asks for username for each user account and returns only ad server name against which the user was last authenticated.

Comment: Look at using System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher - you can use it to return a list of all users then run the query for the last login against that list. `$searcher = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher`

Answer (score 1):

Look [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx) the one you need is `Get-ADUser` command.